# Grub2 menu won't appear in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows-10

So I recently dual booted Ubuntu 14.04 onto a Windows 10. I handled the partitioning correctly. I checked that it is there after a reboot and I have a installed it with 
secure boot off,
hibernation off, 
system protection off, 
and a power setting off. 
Yet my computer goes straight to Windows 10 with no Grub prompt to choose Linux. I have press/held the shift, f1, f2, f10, f11, f12 key and only the f12 key has brought up a menu, however the menu only appears when the install USB is in and my only choices are to boot Windows or INSTALL Ubuntu.

How can I fix this so a grub menu appears on boot?

I have seen in other posts a mysterious etc/grub folder, can i edit this from Windows? If so, where is this folder?

Answer (score 0):

What I think has happened is that the GRUB bootloader got overwritten when Windows was installed.

This seems to be the quickest way to fix it:

1. Boot Ubuntu live via a CD or another method
2. Open a terminal in the live session and run

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
   ```

   this installs the boot repair utility, which will reinstall GRUB, and hopefully fix your problem
3. Type `boot-repair` into the console
4. Using the recommended repair will attempt to fix the problem, and if it fails it will generate a pastebin link which you can post on the original question to provide further details.

Further reading: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair